# Why can't flow cast to a less specific type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Very simplified version of what I'm running into:

```
(({a: 42}: {a?: number}): {a?: number, b?: number})
```

Flow complains that the first object doesn't contain `b`, but `b` is optional.  Why?

Comment: If you could do that, you could also do [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAhgFygDeeA-EegK4C2ARgKYBOANKHRaDkwJboDmAX1ABeEoVAAWAExs6RAOSRYsBYNQYc7IqU7V6zYWLwasuFDvKVajVuz03Do9olBv3H1ADo6zgKyIeD6gAGQh+D5e2LAAqgAOccwAwniYDAAUAJSgIKAASlTo2Dw0DKDMTLBMQA). Notice how the type of `b` magically changes.

Comment: You can go around this error [by creating a clone of the object](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAhgFygDeeA-EegK4C2ARgKYBOANKHRaDkwJboDmAX1ABeEoVAAWAExs6RAOSRYsBYNQYc7IqU7V6zYWLwasuFDvKVajVuz03DokqAB07uqHWpXngGR+oCi+rtiwAGI8AB4MACYAFNIAlKAgoABKVOjYPDQMoMxMsExAA) but that's not quite sound either.

Comment: @noppa -- what about `(({a: 42}: {|a?: number|}): {a?: number, b?: number})`

Comment: Then you could add a new property `b` to the original object through the other one, like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAhgFygDeAPvgPxHoCuAtgEYCmATqKQL6gC8J+RAFgBMoDqgw5QDIsUrV6zFgBopVUDhYBLdAHNRPfMgYA6BgYDkkWLHOIrbABRosuANZMAnqFiRQAeQYAKyYUbGN3D0wHPABKGJJEUHwAbQiAXVAAMkyU9ONsWAAxTQAPJgATByF4kFAAJRp0bE06JlBWFlhlUEK4eHxMTHomTHxoaFAANzxoGhH8FjbaRlZMRA4gA) and the `{|a?: number|}` wouldn't be correct anymore.

Comment: If you make `b` *covariant*, though, [then it'll work](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAhgFygDeAPvgPxHoCuAtgEYCmATqKQL6gC8J+RAFgBMoDqgw5QDIsUrV6zFgBpQAagZVQOFgEt0Ac1E98yEKADCedAHJcAE1ihsACx2Z86AJ51YLJgUQzBgA6BmNrSFhYa0RItgAKNCxcAGsmT1BYSFAAeQYAKyYUbGC0z0x4vABKKpJEUHwAbTKAXVAAMnam1uDsWAAxHQAPJjt4oVqzAFEAN1ZPFz1DN0yUxA4gA)